# Can you have more than one condition on an iff function?

Tags: kql

I have one line of code that is like this

```
| extend Has_Changed = iff(NextBIP15 == PreviousBIP15, 0, 1)
```

and I was wondering if it is possible to add extra conditions to "iff" and in that case what would be the syntax in order to do this?

I would like to do something like

```
| extend Has_Changed = iff(NextBIP15 == PreviousBIP15 AND NextBIP14 == PreviousBIP14, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend Has_Changed = iff((NextBIP15 == PreviousBIP15) and (NextBIP14 == PreviousBIP14), 0, 1)`

?

That is, collect the predicates in parentheses....

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I wanted to know